# c# if i need just one table, should i be using DataSet or DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding

here is my code.

```
public DataSet ConnectandReadList()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    string connection_string="Data Source=hermes;database=qcvalues; Integrated Security=SSPI;";            

    using (var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connection_string))
    {

        myConnection.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand(InitializeQuery(), myConnection);
        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }

    return ds;

}
```

i then set the datasource this way:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

the question is should i be returning a dataset or datatable? how would my code change if i were to be returning datatable?

Comment: Make sure you wrap the `command` and `adapter` pieces in a `using` statement as a couple of the answers have shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just return a DataTable when in your situation.  And the more correct code is

```
using (var command = new SqlCommand(InitializeQuery(), myConnection))
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
    adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the word `DataSet` to `DataTable` and recompile.  You will get an error where you consume this method's result, but you just need to change `dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];` to `dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;`

Comment: While you are at it, change the word ds to something more meaningful...like the actual name of the table. DataTable customersTable or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace all of your `DataSet` by `DataTable` (and for readability, all `ds` by `resultTable`) - or did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

http://imar.spaanjaars.com/406/filling-a-datatable-or-dataset-the-quick-way

```
private DataTable GetDataTable()
{
  string sql = "SELECT Id, Description FROM MyTable";
  using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, myConnection))
    {
      myConnection.Open();
      using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
      {
        DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
        myTable.Load(myReader);
        myConnection.Close();
        return myTable;
      }
    }
  }
}
```